# CakePHP Virtual Fields send headers?

Tags: php, cakephp

I have the Users table with the following data:

```
class User extends Entity
{

protected $_virtual = ['createdformated','modifiedformated'];

protected function _getCreatedformated()
{
    $date = new Time($this->_properties['created']);
    $final=strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M", $date->getTimestamp());
    return $final;
}

protected function _getModifiedformated()
{
    $date = new Time($this->_properties['modified']);
    $final=strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M", $date->getTimestamp());
    return $final;
}
}
```

If in my controller i call:

```
    $logusers["data"] = $this->Logusers->find('all')
       ->contain(['Users'])
       ->order(['Logusers.id'=>'DESC']);

     echo json_encode($logusers);
```

And i get the following after the jsonenconde

```
 Warning (512): Unable to emit headers. Headers sent in file=C:\wamp\www\otras\mailing\src\Controller\UsersController.php line=91 [CORE\src\Http\ResponseEmitter.php, line 48]
```

If i leave only 1(ONE) virtual field, the problem is gone... the problem is only when i enable both of them.

What is the problem???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your echo there.

Do the proper way of [sending JSON via CakePHP](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html) or pass the json to the response body and return the response in your controller action.

Comment: is this the right approach?

        $this->response->type('json');
        $this->response->body(json_encode($logusers));

Comment: Should work as well. However I personally would prefer the JSON view because it doesn't require you to add request specific code to the action. Cake will detect that the request is JSON and configure the response accordingly for you.

Comment: Well, is just im looking at the documentation and is not that explained, it tells me to load the component and set the _serialize, but nothing happens.

Comment: Inspect your request. You must send Accept: application/json. Or add a detector to the request and enable the extension parsing: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#file-extensions